# Не работает try...except с argparse

Tags: python

Следующий код должен принимать параметр с аргументом. Если у параметра не задали аргумент, то должна отловиться ошибка в блоке `except`, но этого не происходит. При этом блок `finally` отрабатывает.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-a', type=int)
try:
    args = parser.parse_args(['-a']) #Здесь ожидается аргумент, но мы его намеренно не передали
    print(args)
except Exception as e:
    print('Exception: %s'%(e))
finally:
    print('Finally section works')
print('End of code')
```

При выполнении кода на выходе видим, что блок `except` не отработал:

```
usage: t.py [-h] [-a A]
t.py: error: argument -a: expected one argument
Finally section works
```

Почему это происходит?

Comment: Потому что argparse не бросает исключение, просто выводит текст. Нельзя поймать исключение, если его нет.

Comment: @insolor, а можно этот момент как то отловить. Ведь он и исключение не бросает, но и программе не даёт завершиться штатно - сообщение ```End of code``` ведь не выводится

Comment: В Python 3.9 можно указать `argparse.ArgumentParser(exit_on_error=False)` (см. [exit_on_error](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#exit-on-error)), тогда будет выводиться.

Comment: @insolor, паршиво - моя система использует Python2.7. Писать свой парсер - не вариант

Comment: Можно взять [исходник](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/argparse.py), если что-то не работает на 2.7 - попробовать адаптировать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрим, что выводит ваш код среди прочего (по крайней мере в Google Colab):

```
SystemExit: 2
```

Ага, значит `argparse` бросает не обычное исключение, а `SystemExit`, которое [не унаследовано от Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26623043/8324991). Поймать это исключение можно, если указать, что мы хотим ловить:

- `SystemExit`
- `BaseException`

То есть вот так исключение поймается и программа доработает до конца:

```
except SystemExit as e:
```

И так тоже:

```
except BaseException as e:
```

Как сказано в приведённой мной ссылке, так сделано специально, чтобы случайно не поймать исключение `SystemExit` типовым блоком программы `except Exception as e:`, всё-таки это особое исключение и ловить его нужно сознательно.